# Bind Tag to ViewModel Property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <DockPanel Width="Auto">
            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Tag="{Binding id}">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate >
                        <Image Source="{Binding image}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template> 
            </Button>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
        </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<Grid x:Name="LeftGrid" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" >
 <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red">
     <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayMovies.View}">
         <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
               <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                   <UniformGrid Columns="5"/>
               </ItemsPanelTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      </ItemsControl>
   </Border>
</Grid>
```

I am setting the `Tag` value of each `Button` to the value of `id`. Whenever a `Button` is selected, I would like to pass this `Tag` value to a `property` in my `ViewModel`.

Could someone please help me out with how I can achieve this? I've always bound from `ViewModel` to `XAML` and never the other way around

I should also mention that `Binding id` is not referring to my `ViewModel`. It is referring to a `property` in `ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayMovies.View}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
 <Button 
    Command="{Binding DataContext.YourVmCommand, 
               RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                   AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"
    DockPanel.Dock="Top" >
```

Comment: Thank you Chris. Just what I was looking for!